# IIS Logging Not Working for WCF Service Calls

Tags: wcf, iis-6

We're experiencing a strange phenomenon where IIS logging works perfectly for normal pages in a site but calls to an .svc URL are not being logged.

Example of a URL that is logged -

http://ourserver/HelloWorld.aspx

Example of a URL that is not logged -

http://ourserver/SampleService.svc/echo/helloworld

(In the second example, Echo is a method on the SampleService contract.)

Both URLs perform as expected.  The call to the first URL is logged just fine, but the call to the second URL never appears in the IIS logs.  We are only seeing this on IIS6; the same site, when running on IIS7 in a different environment, works perfectly and we see all the expected logging.

It's hard to know if it's a WCF issue or an IIS issue.  Does IIS6 have the capacity to exclude certain URL patterns (e.g., .svc) from logging?  Are there any known conditions that can cause this sort of "selective logging" to manifest?  Any insight would be much appreciated.  Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Same experience here - the .svc call is only logged if I access it via a browser. Possibly IIS detects something in the HTTP headers and decides not to log. Did you manage to find a workaround?

Comment: More specifically, it is calls made by BizTalk 2009 to our WCF 3.5 services hosted on W2003 server which aren't being logged. However, if I open a browser and navigate to the same .svc URL, the call is logged (albeit as a GET). But other POSTS are being logged.